# pywinauto to get MessageBox message content

Tags: python, windows, ui-automation, messagebox, pywinauto

I've googled but did not find the answer.
In **python 2.7, Windows**, it is easy to get TextBox content or MessageBox title by

```
app.Dialog.Edit.WindowText()
app.Dialog.WindowText()
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the message content, as in the pic:
[image]

I've tried something like `.Message`, `.Information`, but no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an edit box. Use the following:

```
 app.Dialog.Static1.window_text()
```

or

```
 app.Dialog.Static2.window_text()
```

if message box contains an icon (it would be matched as `Static1`).

Comment: How could a programmer know `Static` is expected? Could you provide a complete **document for pywinauto**?

Comment: Maybe current documentation is not so complete as it could, but you can start from here: http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/contents.html Docs related issues: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Adocumentation (could be useful for debugging tips and tricks - will move to the docs later).

Comment: To know which names are expected use `app.Dialog.PrintControlIdentifiers()`

Comment: Thank you! The pages you provided are very useful!